# Why is there a need to set up air route between India and Afghanistan?

Tags: india, pakistan, afghanistan

Recently India and Afghanistan set up an [air freight corridor](http://www.thehindu.com/news/national/india-afghanistan-open-air-freight-route/article19104598.ece) to by pass Pakistan's presence over their mutual trade. Why they need to do so, if they are sharing borders. What is the exact role of Pakistan and now why it is creating problem in trade?

Comment: Where do you get the "to by pass Pakistan's presence" bit from. From your link, the corridar will pass through Pakistan aerospace, which is not quite the same thing.

Comment: @SJuan76 now a days India Afghan trade routed through Pakistan, and Pakistan is not clearing the trucks stranded at the border that is the reason why India need it

Comment: The point is that, if the corridor goes through Pakistan airspace, then Pakistan can simply refuse to allow the planes to fly through. It does not "bypass" much.

Comment: @SJuan76 it means if any UK flight is passing through Indian Air space then India can put restriction on it whenever it want?

Comment: Yes. Of course, if one country abuses this power, it can expect retaliation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_sovereignty. In fact, many countries have signed a set of treaties called "Freedoms of the air" that grants the signataries several rights, including the "First freedom" that is the right for commercial flights to overfly other signatory countries. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedoms_of_the_air#First_freedom. But Pakistan could at any moment just dismiss the treaty, if it is willing to assume the cost of it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Typically, air cargo is rather different than train/truck/ship cargo. Air transport is expensive, so air cargo is usually restricted to valuable or perishable goods that need to be moved quickly.
- [Take a look](https://www.google.es/maps/@35.6077273,74.0825982,6.41z) at "the common frontier":

  1. Goes through those little hills called the Himalayas, through a region with few roads, and the few roads there seem to have one lane for each direction at most.
  2. Gets into Afghanistan through the "panhandle" at its extreme NE border, forcing to a very long detour.
  3. In relation with the above, in the map it seems as if there is not any road going directly from India to Afghanistan.
  4. Goes through a "hot" spot like Jammu & Kashmir, which has been the place for a lot of infighting.